# Yii2 lajax translate manager scan error

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

When I try to run the ./yii translate/scan command, I got this error message after the Extreacting messages: 
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Unable to locate message source for category 'DbMessageSource'.'

config/web.php

```
'components' => [
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            '*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
                'db' => 'db',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'hu-HU', // Developer language
                'sourceMessageTable' => '{{%language_source}}',
                'messageTable' => '{{%language_translate}}',
                'forceTranslation' => true,
                'cachingDuration' => 86400,
                'enableCaching' => true,
            ],
        ] 
    ],
    'translatemanager' => [
        'class' => 'lajax\translatemanager\Component',
    ],
    'modules' => [
         'class' => 'lajax\translatemanager\Module',
        'layout' => '//main',        
        'allowedIPs' => ['*'],         
        'roles' => ['Admin'],              
    ]
]
```

config/console.php

```
'modules' => [
    'translatemanager' => [
        'class' => 'lajax\translatemanager\Module',
        'tmpDir' => 'runtime',         // Writable directory for the client-side temporary language files. 
                                        // IMPORTANT: must be identical for all applications (the AssetsManager serves the JavaScript files containing language elements from this directory).
        //'root' => '@app',               // The root directory of the project scan.
        'phpTranslators' => ['::t'],    // list of the php function for translating messages.
        'jsTranslators' => ['lajax.t'], // list of the js function for translating messages.
        'patterns' => ['*.js', '*.php'],// list of file extensions that contain language elements.
        'ignoredCategories' => ['yii'], // these categories won’t be included in the language database.
        'ignoredItems' => ['config'],   // these files will not be processed.
        'scanTimeLimit' => null,        // increase to prevent "Maximum execution time" errors, if null the default max_execution_time will be used
        'searchEmptyCommand' => '!',    // the search string to enter in the 'Translation' search field to find not yet translated items, set to null to disable this feature
        'defaultExportStatus' => 1,     // the default selection of languages to export, set to 0 to select all languages by default
        'defaultExportFormat' => 'json',// the default format for export, can be 'json' or 'xml'
        'tables' => [                   // Properties of individual tables
            [
                'connection' => 'db',   // connection identifier
                'table' => '{{%language}}',         // table name
                'columns' => ['name', 'name_ascii'], //names of multilingual fields
                'category' => 'database-table-name',// the category is the database table name
            ],
        ]
    ],
],
'controllerMap' => [
    'translate' => \lajax\translatemanager\commands\TranslatemanagerController::className(),
],
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong with my config or missing something?

Comment: Have you got `db` component set?

Comment: Yes, I am using postgresql and that it works

Comment: This error comes from Yii 2 core and it looks like you have got somewhere in your code something like `Yii::t('DbMessageSource', ...` which is most probably wrong. Am I right?

Comment: I know what you think, but I am not use the 'DbMessageSource' category. 
The DbMessageSource extends [[MessageSource]] and represents a message source that stores translated messages in database.

Comment: It's true but the error you've got comes from [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.11.2/framework/i18n/I18N.php#L200) and the reason you see it is either you've got this category set somewhere or lajax does that somehow because of misconfiguration (?).

Comment: Thank you but I know the error message came from here, that's why I don't understand this behavior. I searched for the 'DbMessageSource' word in my app and I cannot find something new just the default i18n classes. :\

Comment: Gosh! I find it! Need to append the same config parts to web and console.php in the basic yii2. Ahh , sorry for troubles and thank you to tried to help me.